# Backbone Javascript: Wait for a function to finish before running another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, asynchronous

I am new to Javascript and I after reading several examples, I still cannot do this. I know I need to use callbacks, but my code doesnt work. Here is what I tried

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(), {
  success: function() {
    return this.collection.each(this.appendEntry);
  }
});
```

`success` never even gets called

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do something when an asynchronous task is completed, you can use promises. For example with `jQuery`:

```
$.when( myAsyncTask() )
.then(function(){
  console.log("Executed when myAsyncTask() is done..");
});
```

If you just want to do something when a Collection data is succesfully fetched, use the `success()` callback method of a `Backbone.Collection.fetch()`

```
myCollection.fetch({
  success: function(data){
    console.log("Your Collection data is available now.");
  }
});
```

Comment: I know of that `success` callback for Collections, but do you know any such method for this function `$(this.el).html(this.template())`. That function doesn't get to properly finish sometimes before `@collection.each(@appendEntry)
` is called

Comment: Are you sure it's not your template method that isn't giving you the correct result? Seems to me that .html() is synchronous

Comment: the template method returns the correct template, because I put some dummy `HTML` in there. But then the `appendentry` method is called instantly and tries to `append` elements to that HTML, but it cant because the HTML isnt loaded when `appendentry` is called

Answer (score 0):

`$(this.el).html()` (or, more succinctly, `this.$el.html()`) is a synchronous function call. No other Javascript code will execute until that function completes.

```
this.$el.html(this.template());
this.collection.each(this.appendEntry);
```

will execute the two statements in order.

Are you, by chance, overriding the Underscore `template()` function somehow, in which case `this.template()` has turned into an asynchronous call? If so, you need to add callback support to your templating code and defer execution of `html()` until it completes.